# Unable To Satisfy Constraints

Tags: ios, autolayout

I am stumped by this constraint issue. I've tried re-working the constraints a number of times but I can't seem to solve the problem

```
2018-02-15 15:01:59.707545-0500 [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
Try this: 
    (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
    (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x61000008bf90 UIButton:0x7fdabc459660.width == 28>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x610000081270 UIImageView:0x7fdabc459d00.width == 22>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x610000083570 UIImageView:0x7fdabc459d00.leading == UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fdabc410000.leading + 16>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x610000082ee0 UILabel:0x7fdabc4593d0.leading == UIImageView:0x7fdabc459d00.trailing + 16>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x610000080b90 UIButton:0x7fdabc459660.leading == UILabel:0x7fdabc4593d0.trailing + 8>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6100000868b0 UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fdabc410000.trailingMargin == UIButton:0x7fdabc459660.trailing + 8>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6180000953b0 UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fdabc410000.width == 0>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x61000008bf90 UIButton:0x7fdabc459660.width == 28>
```

NSLayoutConstraint:0x6180000953b0 UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fdabc410000.width == 0 makes me suspicious but I'm not sure where that constraint is coming from

Edit:

Here is a picture of the cell with the constraints highlighted. All of the constraints are being created in the storyboard

[image]
[image]

Comment: Explain more about how all this gets set up to begin with. Are all the constraints created in the storyboard? What about the constraints on the table view itself?

Comment: show your constraints man... all of them, and describe the context on how you lay out your tableView

Comment: Also: Use the View Debugger! It will show you your view layout and you will probably see immediately what the problem is.

Comment: is the cell presented as you expect?

Comment: "All of the constraints are being created in the storyboard" And the storyboard never complains about there being any problem? No red or yellow alert in the storyboard? What about the table view _itself_? How does that get configured? I am suggesting that perhaps the table view itself has a width issue.

Comment: Yeah, no complaints in the storyboard. The view controller is instantiated by the storyboard by a segue. The view controller is a TableViewController so there shouldn't be any width issues. Maybe there is something code wise that I'm missing. It's a complicated screen

Comment: select "View as" and switch to other devices and check if storyboard give any complain or warning.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing, plz change content compression resistance priority of both "address and name label" to 740 and check.
[image]